# Determining the tails of a convolution from its behavior on a compact set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, probability-distributions, harmonic-analysis

Let $p$ be a smooth (say, $C^\infty$, but this is not crucial) density on the interval $I=[0,1]$ and $g_\sigma$ be the density of $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Define $f=p\ast g_\sigma$. **To what extent does the behavior of $f$ on $I$ determine its behavior *off* of $I$?** In other words, is it possible that $f=g$ on $I$ but $f\ne g$ on $I^c$? The idea is to determine the tail behavior of $f$ given only information on $I$.

This question is clearly nonsensical without the convolution structure on $f$. Note also that we do not know $p$, but $f$, on the interval $I$. My intuition is that since $p$ *fully* determines the behavior of $f$ globally, the "rough" information given by $f$ on $I$ might be enough to tell us about its tails.

(Note: I am also curious what happens if $p$ is not smooth or has weaker regularity in general, but this is not essential at the moment.)

Comment: $f$ is entire, so is certainly determined by its values on $[0,1]$. (And this does work under much weaker assumptions on $p$.)

Comment: Is there a characterization of when $p\ast g_\sigma$ is an entire function? Appealing to analyticity was a bit more of a hammer than I expected, but without a doubt this would work.

Comment: I don't know about a characterization, but as long as $p$ is compactly supported, there isn't much that can go wrong.